# factoextra package: How can I plot my clusters using variable axes and not PCA component axes?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, k-means, factoextra

```
library(cluster)
km.res <- kmeans(my_data, 4, nstart = 25)
# Visualize
library("factoextra")
fviz_cluster(km.res, data = my_data, frame.type = "convex")+
theme_minimal()
```

[image]

I would like to change the axes to other variables. How can I do that? Is it possible to gather the source of this plot, so maybe I can try to write a completely new plot with variables on the axes?

Thank you.

Comment: What "other variables" are you trying to plot? Do you want to use the `kmeans` data at all? What exactly are you trying to keep from this plot? R has very many plotting functions depending on what you need.

Comment: @MrFlick I'd like to keep the formatting of the plot (cluster membership coloring & framing), but I also would like to change the axis X to variable X and axis Y to variable Y, too. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

@Ubel Yildmar, yes its possible to change the `x` and `y` axis labels.

This answer comes after a long time, but I hope someone might find it useful. One of the arguments of the `fviz_cluster` function are `xlab` and `ylab`. These can be used to change the labels on the `x` and the `y` axis. Type, `?fviz_cluster()` at the R console for the documentation. I now provide a minimum reproducible example;

```
library(cluster)
data(mtcars)
km.res <- kmeans(mtcars, 4, nstart = 25)
# Visualize
library("factoextra")
fviz_cluster(km.res, data = mtcars, ellipse.type ="convex",
         xlab = "x-axis label", ylab = "y-axis label")+
theme_minimal()
```

[image: Cluster Plot]